# maven module referencing itself during install command

Tags: java, maven

When I run maven install I get following  message -

> Failed to execute goal on project Ret: Could not resolve dependencies
>   for project com.software.org:Ret:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
>   artifact com.software.org:Ret:jar:1.0

Here's my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.software.nagibator</groupId>
    <artifactId>Ret</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <compiler>1.8</compiler>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nag.software</groupId>
            <artifactId>SpringContainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.187</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.software</groupId>
            <artifactId>nag</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.software.org</groupId>
            <artifactId>SpringProxyProvider</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${compiler}</source>
                    <target>${compiler}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Post your `pom.xml`. You are probably declaring `Ret` as a dependency when you shouldn't.

Comment: Maybe your custom artifacts wants to load on one of their dependencies your artifact. Use exclusions if so.

Comment: Try to search for your project package inside the pom file

Comment: Was a solution found to this problem?

Comment: @Dev2017  I found that I included my project into the dependency list, so that produced a circular reference. I simply dropped that specific dependeny and all was good.